# Dynamically adding mixin to a model

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopback

I have written a mixin and called it "AuthenticatedFields". It's similar to [read-only](https://github.com/fullcube/loopback-ds-readonly-mixin) mixin, however, it also takes user roles into consideration. It takes property name and role name as input, and strip data if user doesn't have role to see that property.

```
// common/models/somemodels.json
"mixins": {
    "AuthenticatedFields": {
      "data": "admin"
    }
}
```

However, I want to do that dynamically, not in model config file. Because user permissions should be able to change.

Is it possible to add/remove/change mixins dynamically?

Comment: What language are you programming in? What framework(s) are you using?

Comment: javascript, nodejs, loopback